# Javascript variable scope when using http.get in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, closures

I would like to pass some variable to the anonymous function that is called by http.get.

Here is an example of code with the issue.

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');

for (var i = 0, len = 3; i < len; i++) {

    var myText = "test"+i;
    var myUrl = "http://www.google.com"

    var options = url.parse(myUrl);
    http.get(options, function (response) {
        var chunks = [];
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', function() {
            console.log(myText);
        });
    });
}
```

What I would like in the console is something like

```
test0
test1
test2
test3
```

but what I get is

```
test3
test3
test3
test3
```

Thanks and regards,

Eric

Comment: By the time you access the variable, `for-loop` is done with `iterations` hence you get the last value after last `increment(i++)`

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var` in the for loop for block scoping

Comment: @js91 Thanks a lot. That did the trick.

Comment: and @Eric don't forget to 'use strict' for using `let` instead of `var` as suggested by @js91